# Custom Configuration of FMT Tags JSTL in Latest Spring Boot 3

Tags: jstl, spring-boot-3

Custom configuration of FMT extends org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.MessageTag, and the corresponding dependencies alternate Jakarta dependency wasn’t available.
Please help me if anyone have any idea how to handle this in latest Spring Boot 3.